# How to prevent desktop apps from mimicking browser requests?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, cors, jwt

I have two Web Apps written in .netcore, `App 1` served the html content and `App 2` is the API that serves the requests of Javascript, both are in the same solution but each have a different port ofcourse. My Scenario is the browser returns the website from `App 1` that includes the signup form and the javascript access the signup functions on the API at `App 2`.

To prevent the API from being accessed by any other website I enabled the `CORS` and added the domain of `App 1` as the only domain allowed to access the API of `App 2` and it worked great but any desktop can mimick this same request headers and access the API and I tested with postman and the API was accessed.

So I added Authorization header so that all the API functions are required to authorize the `JWT bearer` token to be accessed.

The problem is how to prevent desktop apps or other non-browser apps in general from accessing it.because of the following:

1- if I put the access token in the response from `App 1` so that javascript can use it to access `App 2` , any other app can get it easily and copy paste it to their app and API will be accessed.

2- If I don't hardcode the token in the response of `App 1` and instead let the javascript access a route that generate a token, then any app can do the same because they can mimick the same request headers of the browser. and the CORS will be useless then.

so what should I do ?

Comment: There's nothing you can do about it. If the browser can send something, so can any other application.

Comment: @Barmar so how can I protect my App to get its `JWT` without other apps taking it. just for the first time of issuing it ?

Comment: I don't think you can. Even if you could, the user could still do the same thing by using the browser's console, so the requests WOULD be coming from the browser.

Comment: @Barmar then how google and others do it ? or they don't at all and just leave their APIs issue tokens to anyone ? I think their must he a solution to this.

Comment: In general, APIs that require a secret token can't be called directly from browsers, they're called from server code.

Comment: @Barmar can you please give me an example ?

Comment: Stripe is an example. They give you two API keys, a "publishable" key and "secret" key. The publishable key is just used when the browser app is converting a credit card to a token. The secret key is used on the back end to charge the credit card.

Comment: The publishable key can't be used when calling the API functions that move money around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> .. but any desktop can mimick
>   this same request headers and access the API and I tested with postman
>   and the API was accessed.

This is true, some http client (e.g. `curl`) are able to alter the `Origin` headers when making a request to the server. Thus, `CORS` should not be your **only** security measure to protect your App 2.

> So I added Authorization header so that all the API functions are
>   required to authorize the JWT bearer token to be accessed.

Yes, this is a good decision, but you don't have to protect **all** api endpoints. You can leave some api open to public, e.g. login or signup.

> The problem is how to prevent desktop apps or other non-browser apps
>   in general from accessing it.because of the ...

In general, your App 1 (I'm assuming it's a JavaScript based web client) should not contains any token on load, instead, it should make a call to App 2's login API and get a jwt token back.

App 1 can cache the token, and use it when calling protected APIs on App 2.

Comment: thank you alot for answering me. I don't know why I got alot of negatives. anyways, You say that I call the App 2's login API to get a JWT token, Does that mean that the app 1 credential that will log with them should be available on load ? if yes then it is available on load and you said not to do that.

Comment: for your info, I am asking this question to protect my Signup route from bots and fake account creations on my system.

Comment: @ahmednader I'm not sure why other down vote your question. I think it's a valid question.

Comment: you can protect your signup route with other methods (like api rate limiter or recaptcha). But I suggest you only do that once bots really happens. Your first choice doesn't protect against bot also.

Comment: In the future, you might have other type of client, like a mobile app that connect to the same App 2 rest api. It's very easy to hack the system if you hardcode the jwt token.